# Convert any date format to system date format

Tags: vb.net

i want give a date from user to string Such as `"2011-10-11"` and for example my system date format is : `dd/mm/YYYY`

How can i convert `2011-10-11` To Default System Date Format ( In My Example : `11/10/2011` )

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim result = DateTime.Parse("2011-10-11").ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: Thanks, But in my system default date format is : `dd/MM/yyyy` But in other system NO !

Comment: @Davood try `ToShortDateString()` or `ToString("g")`. See this [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for more formatting related info.

Comment: Have Good Method For change system date ?

Comment: @Davood what do you mean by "change system date" ? do you mean to change system clock from code?

Comment: @Davood I don't think there is any function in .net framework but you can call [`SetSystemTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942(v=vs.85).aspx) winapi call. There are plenty of examples out there. http://www.geekpedia.com/code117_Get-And-Set-The-System-Date-And-Time.html